# Get NSString as NSArray from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've the following data in NSDictionary for an object `field_names` that has below value.

```
{dBur0z9,nr8r0,R0ru,jrurw,qB5rz9ry},{gr2,Z5uzr,Rwxyr5z0Ar5},^~gr2~cry69v~br9rtyz~Z03r4rsru^~Z5uzr~Uvy3z~dB4srz^5B33,(),9ruI,evD3rsv3,,HLK,evDsBAA65,evDtyvt2s6E,5B33,5B33,5B33,5B33,{6ww},SRiTfUV,5B33,5B33,5B33,5B33
```

I'm trying to get it as NSArray. I tried

```
`NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"field_name"];
```

But that returns an NSString not an NSArray. Then I tried to replace { } with [ ] and appended [ ] to make it json array,

```
NSString *s =[[dictionary objectForKey:@"field_names"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@"["];

 s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@"]"];

s= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]",s];

 NSDictionary *temp = @{@"array":s };

 NSLog(@"%@", [temp objectForKey:@"array"]);
```

But still I'm getting it as NSString

```
[[dBur0z9,nr8r0,R0ru,jrurw,qB5rz9ry],[gr2,Z5uzr,Rwxyr5z0Ar5],^~gr2~cry69v~br9rtyz~Z03r4rsru^~Z5uzr~Uvy3z~dB4srz^5B33,(),9ruI,evD3rsv3,,HLK,evDsBAA65,evDtyvt2s6E,5B33,5B33,5B33,5B33,[6ww],SRiTfUV,5B33,5B33,5B33,5B33]
```

Please help me getting it NSArray!

Comment: It seems your data is json. You can deserialize it and can get in form of array.

Comment: I actually had multiple records as JSON, dictionary object is a single record.

Comment: Then you may seprate record by "," and can get in form of NSArray

Comment: yes I tried that but elements within { } also has "," . So the result is not as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any cocoa method for this task, so I replaced `,` with `&` that occurs within `{}` and then used `[string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` method to get it as NSArray. Below is the code

```
-(NSString *)prepareFields:(NSString *)string {

NSString *remainingString =string;
NSString *newString = @"";
@try {

    while ([remainingString rangeOfString:@"{"].location != NSNotFound ) {

        NSUInteger from = [remainingString rangeOfString:@"{"].location ,
        to =[remainingString rangeOfString:@"}"].location+1 ;

        NSString *part = [[remainingString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(from,to)] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"&"];

        remainingString = [remainingString substringFromIndex:to];

        if([newString isEqualToString:@""])
            newString = [part substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([part rangeOfString:@"{"].location,[part rangeOfString:@"}"].location+1)];

        newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",newString,[part substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([part rangeOfString:@"{"].location,[part rangeOfString:@"}"].location+1)]];
    }

}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"break %@" ,[exception reason]);
}

if([newString isEqualToString:@""])
    newString = remainingString;
else
    newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",newString,remainingString];

return newString;   
}
```

And then called it

```
NSLog([[dictionary objectForKey:@"form"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]);
```

That gave following array

```
(
"{dBur0z9&nr8r0&R0ru&jrurw&qB5rz9ry}",
"{dBur0z9&nr8r0&R0ru&jrurw&qB5rz9ry}",
"{gr2&Z5uzr&Rwxyr5z0Ar5}",
"",
"^~gr2~cry69v~br9rtyz~Z03r4rsru^~Z5uzr~Uvy3z~dB4srz^5B33",
"()",
9ruI,
evD3rsv3,
"",
HLK,
evDsBAA65,
evDtyvt2s6E,
5B33,
5B33,
5B33,
5B33,
"{6ww}",
SRiTfUV,
5B33,
5B33,
5B33,
5B33 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting it as a string because it is in fact string. I feel like you're trying to parse it as a JSON string??

If so, you first need to have that string in a valid JSON format. Here's an example JSON

```
{
   "AnArray": [
      "string 1",
      "string 2",
      "string 3"
   ]
}
```

(without the line breaks of course I just added them for readability)

Once you have it as a valid JSON formatted string, you can do this

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [dictionary[@"field_names"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
NSArray* YourArray = json[@"AnArray"];
```